# Sometimes eclipse debugger fails with the message:Failed to execute MI command

Tags: gdb, eclipse-cdt

Usually this happens when I inspect a vector (in debug mode and build). Some of its elements appear normally but some others have a text displaying "Failed to execute MI command..." [for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arU9u.jpg). I tried messing around with the settings and searching with google but with no luck.

Any help is much appreciated.

Some info:

g++ --version

```
g++ (GCC) 9.1.1 20190503 (Red Hat 9.1.1-1)
```

gdb --version

```
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora 8.3-2.fc30
```

eclipse version:

```
Version: 2019-03 (4.11)
```

java -version

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
```

Also tested on different hardware with fedora 30, with all updates applied and the same thing happened.

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> input={1,2,3};
    input.resize(2000);
    std::cout << "test1" << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might have better luck getting an answer on [cdt-dev](https://accounts.eclipse.org/mailing-list/cdt-dev).